# issues with java and printf and decimals

Tags: java

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sdusti00lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double AA = 8.25;
        double CA = 6.50;
        double ACP = 9.00;
        double CPC = 6.25;

        int numA, numC;
        double numSP, numLP;
        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" enter number of adults ");
        numA = keys.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" enter number of children ");
        numC = keys.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" enter number of small popcorn");
        numSP = keys.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" enter number of large popcorn");
        numLP = keys.nextDouble();
        double  AAddPrice = (numA*AA);
        double  CAddPrice = (numC*CA);
        double  ACPT = ((ACP*.094)*AA);
        double CPCT = ((CPC*.094)*CA);
        double SPTax = (ACP*.094);
        double LPTax = (CPC*.094);
        System.out.println("Adult admission "+"\t"+numA + "\t$" + AAddPrice);
        System.out.println("Child admission  "+"\t"+numC + "\t$" + CAddPrice);
        System.out.println("Adult popcorn  "+"\t\t"+ACP + "\t$" + ACPT);
        System.out.println("Child popcorn  "+"\t\t"+CPC + "\t$" + CPCT);
        System.out.println("Tax  "+"\t\t\t$"+ (SPTax + LPTax));
        System.out.println("Total "+"\t\t\t$"+(AAddPrice+CAddPrice+CPCT+ACPT) ); 
    }
}
```

I need to change the last 6 lines of code to produce a decimal that stops at the number second to the decimal, but I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hint: variable names go camelCase - always. So they never start Uppercase (except for CONSTANTS). Then: for each second you save on typing **short** variable names you later spend a minute figuring "what was that about again". So: use names that mean something.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.printf` or `System.out.format` to do this. Use `%.2f` for printing upto two decimal point.

```
System.out.printf("Adult admission \t%d\t$%.2f%n", numA, AAddPrice);
```

Comment: I think that is what you meant ;)

Comment: And since we are already using `printf` why won't we get rid of these `\t`? Wasn't that one of main reasons why `printf` exist?

Comment: System.out.printf("Tax \t%d\t$%.2f%n", (SPTax+LPTax));
System.out.println("Total "+"\t\t\t$"+(AAddPrice+CAddPrice+CPCT+ACPT) ); super helpfull! but for some reason these last two are not working right. j

Comment: Reove %d from the first and add %.2f to the second line: `System.out.printf("Tax \t$%.2f%n", (SPTax+LPTax));` `System.out.println("Total \t$%.2f%n",(AAddPrice+CAddPrice+CPCT+ACPT) );`

Comment: Also, as @GhostCat mentioned, study this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html for learning more anout formatting in java.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to turn numbers (float, double, ..) into formatted Strings. Oracle has a nice [overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) worth studying.

The important aspect to understand here: that process works by you

A) specifying a **format** that describes how your output should look like

B) you calling a **formatter** with that format and the numbers to format